# Intercepting XMLHttpRequest originating from third party components to SetRequestHeader. But xhr readyState sometime showing UNSENT

Tags: javascript, angular, xmlhttprequest

We are trying to intercept all the xhr request in angular application to setRequestHeader.

here is the code example trying.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    uuid:string = '1234';
    ngOnInit() {
        this.httpRequestInterceptInit();
    }
    httpRequestInterceptInit() {
        const openRequest = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
        let self = this;

        window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(
            method: string,
            url: string
        ) {

            // `this` is the caller for `open` which is expected to be some `XMLHttpRequest`.
            let xhr: XMLHttpRequest = this;
            fromEvent(xhr, 'readystatechange').pipe(first()).subscribe(() => {
                if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.OPENED) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('x-d-uuid', self.uuid);
                }
            });

            return openRequest.apply(this, arguments as any);
        }
    }

}
```

everything seems works fine but some times http request not getting inside if condition execution `if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.OPENED) { xhr.setRequestHeader('x-d-uuid', self.uuid); }` and `xhr.readyState` value showing `UNSENT`. due to that facing issue like http request header does not includes `x-d-uuid` header in network http call.

What could be the issue.Is there any unseen issue in above code? Any help is very much appriciated.

Thanks!